# Strong Stationary Time of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, intuition

## Definitions.

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a Markov chain on a finite state space $\Omega$. Assume the Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic.
So there is a unique stationary distribution $\pi$.

An $\mathbb N$ valued random variable $T$ is called a **stopping time** if the event $T=t$ depends only on $X_0, \ldots, X_t$ (I guess this formally means that $T=t$ is measurable in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_0, \ldots, X_t$).

A stopping time $T$ is called a **strong stationary time** (SST) if
$$P[X_t=x|T=t]= \pi(x)$$
for all $x\in \Omega$.

Let $p^{(t)}_x(y)$ denote the probability that $X_t=y$ if the chain starts at $x$, that is, if $P[X_0=x]=1$.
We write $\Delta_x(t)$ to denote the total variation distance between $p^{(t)}_x$ and $\pi$.

---

## Questions.

Let $T$ be a strong stationary time.
In [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esinclair/cs294/n4.pdf) document, Claim 4.2 states that
$$\Delta_x(t)\leq P[T>t|\ X_0=x]$$
and the author says that this should be intuitively reasonable.

> I am quite stumped. Can somebody elaborate on as to what is the intuitive reason to expect this. In fact, I do not have much in the way of intuition regarding the very concept of SST.

Next, in the proof of Claim 4.2 on Pg 4, a line reads

"... we denote by $T_x$ the SST for the chain started at state $x$..."

> I am not sure what is the meaning of this. Does this mean that for each $x$ there is associated a (unique) SST?